# Query regarding SQLite and Cascading foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, c#-4.0, cascade

I am currently writing a application in C# that uses a SQLite database to store information the user will input. The application is basically a Management system for users who are called "Students" in the application. This is the most important table in my database and every other table is linked off this table. What I want to do is when a student is removed - they leave the institute/get kicked out etc. - is to remove their data from all the other tables so that data is no longer there as it isn't needed. An example of some of the Create table statements I have written is:

```
CREATE TABLE student(studentID int(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name string(16),...,DOB string(8) );

CREATE TABLE emergencyContact(emergencyID int(5) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name string(16),..., contactNumber int(16));

CREATE TABLE emergencyContactOf(studentID int(5) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES student('studentID'), emergencyID int(5) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES emergencyContact('emergencyID');
```

I have read up on this and my understanding is the data will be deleted in the EmergencyContactOf table if I include a 'ON DELETE CASCADE' statement as the StudentID key will no longer be present in the Parent table.

However, my understanding is the data in the EmergencyContact table that is for that specific student will not be deleted as there is no reference to the StudentID.

My question is, is there a way to remove the data from this table also that is relevant to that Student? For example, if I was to include a column in the EmergencyContact table which would reference the StudentID as a Foreign Key and then remove that row if the StudentID is ever deleted from the parent table? Is this a good solution to this particular problem?

All other tables I have are also designed in this way, where the data is in different tables and then linked back to the Student table with relationship tables so this will also apply to all the other tables I have.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't answer your problem, but you really want to be using [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), not `int(5) PRIMARY KEY` to make your tables more efficient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, is there a way to remove the data from this table also that is relevant to that Student? For example, if I was to include a column in the EmergencyContact table which would reference the StudentID as a Foreign Key and then remove that row if the StudentID is ever deleted from the parent table? Is this a good solution to this particular problem?

What happens if multiple students have the same emergency contact? You don't want to duplicate data if you don't have to - that's the whole point of the emergencyContactOf table, to efficiently set up a many to many relation between students and emergency contacts. So you don't want to do something like you describe.

You could periodically (Monthly, yearly, after purging student rosters, whatever) run a delete that removes rows from emergencyContact if they don't appear in emergencyContactOf:

```
DELETE FROM emergencyContact
WHERE emergencyID NOT IN (SELECT emergencyID FROM emergencyContactOf)
```

or the like.

Comment: Thanks Shawn - hadn't considered that scenario but definitely one that will be occuring in all tables - multiple parents etc. - so will be using the second SQL command you've suggested. Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I see two scenarios here. What if two students have the same emergency contact, say two bothers having their father as emergency contact?

1. If in such a case you store only one record (the father) in the emergency contact table, you don't want to delete the emergency contact if only one of them leaves. You'd delete the emergency contact for the other one. So you'd need additional logic, when to delete an emergency contact. You could put that in a trigger.
2. You use a less sophisticated approach and multiple rows from the emergency contact table can map to one person in real life. In that case you can pull the reference to the student directly into the emergency contact table and use `ON DELETE CASCADE` there.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE student
                (studentid int(5),
                 name string(16),
                 ...
                 PRIMARY KEY (studentid),
                 ...);
   ...
   CREATE TABLE emergencycontact
                (emergencycontactid int(5),
                 studentid int(5),
                 name string(16),
                 ...
                 PRIMARY KEY (emergencycontactid),
                 FOREIGN KEY (studentid)
                             REFERENCES student
                                        (studentid),
                 ...);
   ```

The second might be tempting but the "clean way" is the first one, as the second allows contradicting data. From what you posted you're already on the "clean way". But a mentioned that required triggers.

Comment: Thank you - hadn't considered or thought about multiple students having the same emergency contact but definitely one I will be considering now. Occurs across multiple tables too - one parent for many students etc. - so will be using the SQL command or a variation of it as suggested by Shawn above.